# Django Rest Framework"detail": "Method \"GET\" not allowed."

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I;m trying to build api by using django rest framework but I got the issue.

```
@api_view(['PUT', ])
def api_update_blog_view(request, title):
    try:
        post = Post.objects.get(title=title)
    except Post.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    if request.method == 'PUT':
        serializer = PostSerializer(post, data=request.data)
        data = {}

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            data["success"] = "update successful"
            return Response (data=data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

```
urlpatterns = [

    path('<str:title>/update', api_update_blog_view, name="update"),


]
```

When I'm trying to update post I can see "detail": "Method "GET" not allowed." error. Where is the issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens when you use the wrong method to call the api. For example you defined the route method as `PUT` in your view but accessing it by `GET` method, hence the error. As of this, you would need a tool to test your apis with proper methods. Try using [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) or [Thunder Client](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rangav.vscode-thunder-client) for VS code.